# SCVMM 2012 SP1 Migration Error

Tags: hyper-v, scvmm, system-center

I have a host grouping of several nearly-identical host machines running WS08R2 SP1. They are all running direct-attached storage of different sizes/raid types. They were running VMM08R2, but I've begun the switch to 2012SP1, and am now no longer able to migrate VMs between several off the hosts with the error "No Connected Storage Device Could be Identified that satisfies all Requirements". This is not uniform however, but does appear to be related to only the hosts with the largest storage pools. I am however able to migrate OFF those machines.

For Example, Here are some sample Migrations:

HOST1 -> HOST2 ERR / HOST3 OK

HOST2 -> HOST1 OK / HOST3 OK

HOST3 -> HOST1 OK / HOST2 ERR

I have tried doing a local-local storage migration on the hosts, to no avail. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, that all SCSI-protocol disks are treated as remote storage in SCVMM 2012. The servers that were having issues had the disks exposed to the OS as SAS-type, while the ones that were ok were exposed as SATA or RAID type disks